# Xpath: select node based in a condition (with local-name())

Tags: xml, xpath

The question is quite silly, but I am completely stuck. I want to extract child nodes of a node based on a condition. The XML is as follows:

```
<a> 
 <aCode>aaa</aCode>
 <aValue>bbb</aValue>
</a>
```

The expression is obvious: `//a[aCode='aaa']`

But I can't get how I should change it if it is with namespaces and I've got to use `local-name()`. I've tested the following  and it gives a parsing error:

```
/*[local-name()='a'][[local-name()='aCode']='aaa']
```

Has anyone any idea of what I should do?

Comment: local-name() is very annoying! XPath loses all its elegance when you start using namespaces... but this was a helpful question

Answer (score 59):

You probably meant

```
//*[local-name()='a'][*[local-name()='aCode']='aaa']
```

Comment: Here what `*` means - `[*[local-name()='aCode']='aaa']` ? Help me to understand please!

Comment: `*` stands for "any element".

Answer (score 19):

**Try this**

```
/a/aCode[text()='aaa']
```

or

```
//*[local-name() = 'aCode' and text() = 'aaa']
```

You have used `//` at wrong place.

Comment: Thanks!
I just wanted to get both children.

Answer (score 5):

This one work:

```
//*[local-name()='a'][*[local-name()='acode' and text()='a2']]
```

and also this one:

```
//*[local-name()='a'][aCode[text()='a2']]
```