# How to write xpath query with default namespace and attribute condition

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
      <Worksheet ss:Name="Name1">
        something
      </Worksheet>
      <Worksheet ss:Name="Name2">
        something else
      </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
```

How the query should look like that would turn me Worksheet element with ss:Name attribute Name1. Because of default namespace i have to set first condition like this:

```
//*[name()="Worksheet"]
```

but i don't know how to add attribute condition...

------- update -------
Because I can't find solution here is all xml file (file generated by excel):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <Author>Don diego</Author>
    <LastAuthor>Don diego</LastAuthor>
    <Created>2013-04-18T07:20:33Z</Created>
    <LastSaved>2013-04-18T07:20:33Z</LastSaved>
    <Company>CEI</Company>
    <Version>14</Version>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <AllowPNG/>
  </OfficeDocumentSettings>
  <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    <WindowHeight>7740</WindowHeight>
    <WindowWidth>13395</WindowWidth>
    <WindowTopX>360</WindowTopX>
    <WindowTopY>30</WindowTopY>
    <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
    <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
  </ExcelWorkbook>
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
      <Borders/>
      <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:CharSet="238" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
      <Interior/>
      <NumberFormat/>
      <Protection/>
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15"/>
    <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <PageSetup>
        <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
      </PageSetup>
      <Selected/>
      <Panes>
        <Pane>
          <Number>3</Number>
          <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
        </Pane>
      </Panes>
      <ProtectObjects/>
      <ProtectScenarios/>
    </WorksheetOptions>
  </Worksheet>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15"/>
    <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <PageSetup>
        <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
      </PageSetup>
      <Selected/>
      <Panes>
        <Pane>
          <Number>3</Number>
          <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
        </Pane>
      </Panes>
      <ProtectObjects/>
      <ProtectScenarios/>
    </WorksheetOptions>
  </Worksheet>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet3">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15"/>
    <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
      <PageSetup>
        <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
        <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
      </PageSetup>
      <Selected/>
      <Panes>
        <Pane>
          <Number>3</Number>
          <ActiveCol>1</ActiveCol>
        </Pane>
      </Panes>
      <ProtectObjects/>
      <ProtectScenarios/>
    </WorksheetOptions>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

I want to get Worksheet element with attribute 'Sheet1' with XPath.
And here is what i've got:

```
$uri = $this->doc->getDocNamespaces()['']; //$this->doc is obiect of simplexmlelement class
$this->doc->registerXPathNamespace('default', $uri); //'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'
$current_worksheet = $this->doc->xpath('/*/default:Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Sheet1"]');
die(var_dump($current_worksheet));//empty array :(
```

For now $current_worksheet is an empty array :( It looks that the default namespace is the same as ss namespace (same urn)?

Comment: The ["dirty hack" is with `local-name()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813653/xpath-select-node-based-in-a-condition-with-local-name), and for the attribues you need to register a prefix so you can use it with your xpath. Also your XML file is *invalid*, you can not have spaces before the root element, I will fix it in your question removing the spaces.

Comment: this xml is just simplify, made by copy, paste

Comment: And is `<Workbook>` the document element? This does make a difference if not, so you should make that chrystal clear otherwise you're asking for the wrong thing;) (I'm not asking if that is the *whole* document, just if the first element is the first element as well in the original XML)

Comment: Double check your example. With the XML and your code (simplexml) it does work for me. also you don't need to register *default:*  because you can use *ss:* instead as you wrote. This is how I outlined it in my answer as well. You might have a little mistake somewhere else, the xpath works :(

Comment: Hmmm... problem can be in the way I add this attribute to the xml, I do it like this 
$ws = $this->doc->addChild('Worksheet');
$ws->addAttribute('xmlns:ss:Name', 'Sheet1');
What You think?

Comment: Well, it does not work that way. If you want to add an attribute in a specific namespace, you need to use the third parameter of [`SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.addAttribute) and also the first parameter is without the colons, so you take `"Name"` only not `"xmlns:ss:Name"`. If you're new to these functions and a problem occurs, always check with the manual. That's the best you can do (and by far the most fast way). Also other users here were better understand your problem if you checked those basics already. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*/ss:Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Name1"]
```

---

You have got two options here. First I start with the one I think that is more correct. It makes use of the namespace. To have it working you need to register the namespace-prefix with the according URI, here for two namespaces:

```
Prefix: default
URI   : urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet

Prefix: ss
URI   : urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet
```

You then can just query:

```
/*/default:Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Name1"]
```

The second variant does exactly the same xpath query, but ignoring the namespace of all non-default namespaces. This works with `local-name()` and is more complex:

```
/*/*[local-name()="Worksheet"][@*[local-name()="Name" and . = "Name1"]]
```

As you can see, the first variant is preferable because it is much more readable. Also it is more distinct as it names each concrete element and not only by the local-name.

Here is a short example how you can register an XML namespace prefix so it can be used with xpath. This is necessary because the default namespace is non-empty:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

$uri = $xml->getDocNamespaces()[''];
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', $uri);

$result = $xml->xpath('/*/default:Worksheet[@ss:Name = "Name1"]');

echo trim($result[0]), "\n"; # something
```

[Online Demo](http://eval.in/16746) - Worth to remember: Like each element, each attribute as well can have its own namespace. Attribute namespaces are not the elements namespace automatically (only the document default ones).

Comment: I've update my question please take a look what can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

More something like that:

Select the '**Worksheet**' element with the '**Name**' attribute value of '**Name1**'.

```
//Worksheet[@ss:Name='Name1']
```

Comment: It won't work because Worksheet belongs to default namespace

Answer (score 0):

```
/x:Workbook/x:Worksheet[@ss:Name='Name1']
```

with the namespace prefixes "x" and "ss" bound in the calling application to the appropriate namespace URIs, using whatever API you are using for running the XPath.

Answer (score 0):

OK i found a reason why hakre's xpath doesnt work for me, i don't know why but this code

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
</Workbook>
XML;
$el = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
$child = $el->addChild('Worksheet');
$child->addAttribute('xmlns:ss:Name', 'Sheet1');
$result = $el->xpath("ss:Worksheet[@ss:Name='Sheet1']");
```

didn't work. I have to create new SimpleXMLElement to make it work, like this:

```
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
</Workbook>
XML;
$el = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);
$child = $el->addChild('Worksheet');
$child->addAttribute('xmlns:ss:Name', 'Sheet1');
$el = new SimpleXMLElement($el->asXML()); //refreshing of SimpleXMLElement
$result = $el->xpath("ss:Worksheet[@ss:Name='Sheet1']"); //now it work like a charm
```

Thank's for help

Comment: This line of code is utterly wrong: `$child->addAttribute('xmlns:ss:Name', 'Sheet1');` consult the manual especially how to add attributes with namespaces: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.addattribute -- Also the question you've asked was not about DOM manupulation, but about doing the xpath query. If you want to know something, you should ask for it, not about something else ;)

Comment: I use addAttribute like this because
$child->addAttribute('ss:Name', 'Sheet1', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');
add index attribute with default namespace ('ss' and 'default' namespaces are the same)